# Stretching an element outside of its parent

Tags: css, css-position

I have 3 divs in my body: a container, a parent, and a child.
I'm trying to get the child to extend outside of its parent on the left side.
But if I do so with `position: absolute`, the parent will not stretch to the desired height...

`position: static`

[image: position: static]

`position: absolute`

[image: position: absolute]

Using a `margin-left: -20px` will not do either: ultimately, i'll have other nested parents, and need *all* the children to extend to the outer left.

Hers's my code so far:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
}

.parent {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.child {
    padding: 30px;
}
```

Any way to do this in pure css?

**Edit:**  Here's my html code so you can see how the parents will be nested in each other:

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>

        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Edit 2:** I have to point out there are multiple (infinite) levels of nesting in my code. The html sample above is just a fragment.

Comment: why not set the `height` for your container and set `height:100%` for your child? absolute position will pull the child out of its parent, the parent does not have explicit `height` set, so it will collapse like as it has no content.

Comment: Actually I need the child to stretch with its content so I won't know the height. Sorry if my question was misleading.

Comment: why absolute to the child then? have you thought of making the parent absolute-positioned instead?

Comment: Absolute positioning doesn't work if I add nested parents inside my original parent (the nested parents will overlap).

Comment: You may want to wrap your class names in quotation marks, it's invalid HTML otherwise `class="classname"`

Comment: Yes I typed that quickly, sorry I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/G2DBu/1/)

```
.child {
    height: 60px;
    position:relative;
    left:-20px;
}
```

You can use `position:relative` to also justify content beyond the borders of a parent, so long as `overflow:hidden` isnt set on the parent.

Comment: I can't get it to work when nesting multiple parents.

Comment: @Westerfaq - seems OK here: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/G2DBu/3/ it may be conflicts elsewhere in your CSS

Comment: The second displayed child should be aligned with the 2 others. To get that I'd have to set `left: -40px` but that's not viable, I'll have 100's of children, I can't calculate the margin for each one of them.

Comment: @Westerfaq that wasnt specified in the question, but can be easily resolved in CSS, add `.parent .parent .child{ left:-40px;
}` http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/G2DBu/4/ - unless...you have many levels of nesting? You may want to update your question with more info

Comment: Exactly, I have multiple levels of nesting, I can't use the simple solutions here.

Comment: @Westerfaq - you wont be able to accomplish this using your current setup I'm afraid as what you're trying to do break the document flow. You'll either need some JS or rethink the layout/what you're trying to accomplish and restructure your HTML.

Comment: Okay then, I'll change the whole structure and try to work something out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this style:

```css
.stretch-block {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

It pushes the element to 50% width of the parent container from the left, then pulls it to the viewport's left edge with a negative margin that's 50% of viewport width. Then the element gets a width that's 100% of viewport width.

Comment: What voodoo magic is this? **_It works!!_** Fully automatic; stretches from edge to edge. No fixed pixel negative margin etc. _Thank you!_ (I suggest expanding the answer with some explanations to improve its quality.)